# Access to Google API from a cron job

Tags: api, oauth, google-api

I have been following the examples on getting access to Googles API using OAuth 2.0, but it bothers me, that I keep needing a security token every time I fire up my application.

You see, I'm writing some scripts that takes advantage of the Prediction API from Google and I can't seem to find a way to bypass the Oauth browser login.

Is there another way? Is there a formal way for applications that don't run in a browser?

Answer (score 1):

There are sample applications in [Python](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg/samples/prediction) and [Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/prediction-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/prediction/cmdline/PredictionSample.java?repo=samples) that make requests to the Prediction API from a command-line application.

In both cases the first time they are run a browser is required to get the token, but subsequent requests refresh the token as needed without requiring a browser.

Both should be good starting points, and it should be possible to have your script include its refresh token as a constant (or passed in from the command line) so that it always gets a newly refreshed access token before making a request.

You will still need to use a browser to get the first token though.

Comment: Since I asked this question, I havn't seen any other solutions to my problem. It seems that I need to find some other way to predict my results, since I can't guarantee that I can restart the process if the token has expired for so long, that I need to resubmit the access.
It will work fine if the program keeps sending keep-alive-beacons to Google, but if the program stops working for some reason, it seems can't be sure the process won't have to be be restarted by a human operator.

Comment: The program doesn't have to refresh the token every hour, it just has to refresh before it makes the request -- when it refreshes, it has an hour before it needs to refresh again.